# MongoDB Update (Insert a List of Item to an Array)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to add several items to arrays of several rows in Mongo.  How can I do this?

I want to start with this:

```
{'x': 'h', arr: [1,2,3] }
{'x': 'h', arr: [1,3] }
```

and add the array [6,8], where the x is equal to 'h':

```
{'x': 'h', arr: [1,2,3,6,8] }
{'x': 'h', arr: [1,6,8] }
```

Answer (score 11):

I think what you are looking for is the $pushAll operator.  Take a look here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pushAll/#pushall

Comment: Looks like the Mongo folks re-organized their docs.  Direct link here:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pushAll/#_S_pushAll

Answer (score 8):

If you have a MongoDB collection named `yourCollection` and a record with the name `x`, you would update the subarray with something like this:

> db.test.update( {"name":"x"}, {"$pushAll" : {arr : [1, 2, 3]}} )

The important keyword here is [$pushAll](http://cn.docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pushAll/).  You can use it to add items to arrays inside of a single record attribute.

Comment: Its deprecated from version 2.4 onwards. Use $each instead

Answer (score 2):

the simplest approach is by using a conventional update operation

```
  db.urColl.update(
    { x: "h" },
    { $push: { arr: { $each: [6,8] } } },
    { multi: true }
  );`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update multiple records, it's important to pass `true` as the 4th argument to the update function:

```
db.test.update( {"name": "x"}, {"$pushAll": {"arr": [1, 2, 3]}}, false, true)
```

Per the MongoDB shell syntax for update():

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

- **upsert** - if the record(s) do not exist, insert one. Upsert only inserts a single document
- **mutli** - indicates if all documents matching criteria should be updated rather than just one

Answer (score 0):

`$pushAll`
Deprecated since version 2.4: Use the `$push` operator with `$each` instead.

The `$pushAll` operator appends the specified values to an array.

The `$pushAll` operator has the form:

```
{ $pushAll: { <field>: [ <value1>, <value2>, ... ] } }
```

If you specify a single value, `$pushAll` will behave as `$push`.